# SMS forwarding to email when phone is switched off

Tags: sms, broadcastreceiver, forward

I am new to andriod programming and I'm having trouble finding any way of forwarding my SMS to my email when my phone is switched off.

The reason I want to do this is because I have my normal phone /sim in the UK, and I spend 3 months abroad. I take my UK sim out and put in a local sim.

I would like to have my UK SMS forwarded to my email, in the same way I am able to forward my missed calls using Hullomail, but I am not sure if this is possible with the Broadcastreceiver.

I am using Android 4.4.4

Answer (score 0):

If your SIM card is removed, you will not receive any SMS messages on that phone for the account the SIM represents. There are apps that will forward SMS messages. You could leave your UK SIM in a phone, plugged in, and running forwarding software to your other phone. Also, your network operator may offer SMS forwarding services.

Comment: Thanks David - I was afraid you would say that ! I guess that means that sms messages don't work in the same way calls work. I don't have my UK sim in any device when I am abroad, but the HulloMail app still forwards all calls. How would the Hullomail app listen for incoming calls and forward them when the sim is not in use ?